# Coldfusion 2021 calls wrong overload method on org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFSheet object

Tags: coldfusion, spreadsheet

The following code stopped working when ported from Coldfusion 2018 to Coldfusion 2021 (Update 6), it was tested on Windows and Apple OSes. Can you help me to find out what's causing the error?
The system has jdk 11.0.19.

```
<cfscript>
cellRange = createObject(
  "java",
  "org.apache.poi.ss.util.CellRangeAddress"
).init( 1, 1, 0, 0 );

document    = spreadSheetNew( "Demo", true );
poiWorkBook = document.getWorkBook();

for( i = 0; i < poiWorkBook.getNumberOfSheets(); i++ ){
  poiSheet = poiWorkBook.getSheetAt( i );

  try{
    poiSheet.setRepeatingRows( cellRange );
  }catch( any e ){
    writeDump( var=poiSheet, label="poiSheet" );
    writeDump( var=cellRange, label="cellRange" );
    writeDump( var = e, label="Sheet #i#" );
  }
}
</cfscript>
```

The detailed error is

> Either there are no methods with the specified method name and argument types or the setRepeatingRows method is overloaded with argument types that ColdFusion cannot decipher reliably

[image: Error dump]

Here's the doc page for poiSheet: [text](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/xssf/usermodel/XSSFSheet.html)

I tried to update Coldfusion 2021 to latest patch and to update jdk to latest version supported by CF21 (11.0.19).

UPDATE: I changed the name of variable cellRange to cellRng, as suggested by Dan Bracuk, but nothing changed. Here's a dump of cellRng:

[image: Content of cellRng]

UPDATE 2: I found a question almost identical to mine in Coldfusion Community. [Coldfusion Community](https://community.adobe.com/t5/coldfusion-discussions/formatting-excel-spreadsheet-issue-after-upgrade-to-cf2021/m-p/13596483).
I submitted a bug report in [Adobe bug tracker](https://tracker.adobe.com/#/view/CF-4218478)

**SOLVED**
`cellRange` has to be initialized this way

```
cellRange = createObject(
  "java",
  "org.apache.poi.ss.util.CellRangeAddress",
  "poi",
  "4.1.2"
).init( 1, 1, 0, 0 );
```

Coldfusions 2021 is shipped with different versions of the POI library and I need to specify which version to use when creating the object.

Comment: What does your `cellRange` variable look like?

Comment: It could be that your variable name is the same as a class name.

Comment: Actually I was referring to the poiSheet variable.

Comment: @DanBracuk I just run the code after prefixing all variables with "test_", still not working.

Comment: This is really confusing, when I tried to run this without `.init( 1, 1, 0, 0 )`, there is no error. Something is up with the internal libraries, or may be it because there are no cells, available in the range.

Comment: This might be some kind of class clash. Don't know ACF, but is it possible that the new ACF engine is coming with a new bundle and now it doesn't know which lib to use?